# XSL Transform Not Recognizing char(10) for excel

Tags: excel, templates, xslt, transform

I am using xsl transform to take xml data and create an xml file that can be read by excel.  I originally created and xls template file from and excel file I wanted my data to look like.  In some of the cells users use Alt Enter for new lines in a cell and I want to be able to do this in the transform.

So, I have in part of my template data file some entries like this:

```
<Code>28890&#10;&#10;&#10;12345</Code>
```

In the template file, I am doing this:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="Code"/></Data></Cell>
```

But when I do the transform to xml, the resulting document, when opened in excel, doesn't recognize the alt enter, so the cells do not have multiple lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new to this, so if there is a better way I would like to know.

Thanks

Comment: It is not the XSLT transformation that is not recognizing &#10; -- it is Excel. Please, change the now misleading title of the question to something correct. This problem means that Excell uses a special way (most probably a special element, to denote a new line. You have to find out what this special way is sothat then you can make your transformation produce conformant output.

Answer (score 0):

I did disocver the answer, and it is the transform xslt.
I changed this:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="Code"/></Data></Cell>
```

To this:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="Code"/></Data></Cell>
```

and my data to use the following for the alt+enter key:

```
&amp;#10;
```

Now just need to figure out how to get the cell to auto expand.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the auto expand, just had to add a style to the cell that forces word wrap:

```
<Style ss:ID="CPTCodeStyle">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Top" **ss:WrapText="1"**/>
      <Font ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1"/>
      <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
    </Style>
```